# Problem deriving b using the master theorem

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computer-science, computational-complexity

Given the definition:
$$
T(n) = aT(n/b) + n^c
$$
I am struggling to derive the value of $b$ from the following problem:
$$
T (n) = T (4n/5) + O(1)
$$

I feel the value is $5/4$, but I am not sure why other than neither $5$ nor $4/5$ looking the right answer.

Whether I am correct or incorrect, please can someone explain the answer; I want to know how I should be thinking about this problem for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $b=\frac54$, then $$\frac nb=\frac{n}{5/4}=\frac{n}{5/4}\times \frac{4/5}{4/5}=\frac{4n}{5}$$
which matches your original expression.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, 5201314 (best name ever)